# why "fucntion body" is returned instead of "function object" when we console log a function?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I have an object "person1" and in it, there is a method "enroll" ==>

```js
      function Person(first, last, age, gender) {
        this.enroll = function abc() {
            console.log("hello world")
        }
        // property and method definitions
        this.name = {
          first: first,
          last: last,
        };
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        //...see link in summary above for full definition
      }

      let person1 = new Person('Bob', 'Smith', 32, 'male', ['music', 'skiing']);

      console.log(person1);
```

My question is why on `console.log(person1.enroll)` `function body or function definition(ƒ abc() {console.log("hello world")})` is returned, why the whole function object is not returned like this =>

```
ƒ abc()
    arguments: null
    caller: null
    length: 0
    name: "abc"
    prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
    [[FunctionLocation]]: oop2.html:12
    [[Prototype]]: ƒ ()
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[2]
```

and why do I have to do `console.dir(person1.enroll)` to see all properties and methods of `enroll` function object. Why `console.log(person1.enroll)` does not give access to all methods and properties inside of enroll function.

Comment: I think it has to do with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to why does `log` produce what it does and `dir` produce what it does is that they are written for a particular reason. According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)

> The intent behind `log` is "for general output of logging information"

> The intent behind `dir` is to "display an interactive listing of the properties of a specified JavaScript object. This listing lets you use disclosure triangles to examine the contents of child objects."

So by intent, `log` does not give you all the properties and methods and other information. `log` is just for "general logging," to give you some hint about the object. We have `dir` for the express purpose of outputting everything. In other words `log` doesn't give you a detailed description because the designers of the console object chose to put that information in `dir`.

(The designers *could* have chosen to output more with `log` but they wanted to reserve that more powerful feature for `dir`. Besides you are probably familiar with out console dot logging general object gives the often useless `[object Object]` so it should not really be a surprise that logging a function does not give full details either.)

Comment: (The behavior of log also changes between browsers..)

Comment: True, but `log` not required to show all the properties and methods the way `dir` is, so it's the simpler of the two

Comment: So what you are saying is log is much simple than dir and it is "predefined" to show "function body" rather than whole "function object". Am I right?

Comment: @KunalKhatri: log is not defined to have a specific output. The first quoted paragraph shows you how it's defined. What **exactly** `console.log(someFunction)` will log depends on how the browser developers interpreted that and can vary between browsers and versions of the same browser.